# How do I convert my t/p value into a prediction or something meaningful?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, predictive-models

I am working with categorical data which has been converted into numerical. Essentially it is antibiotic resistances to certain diseases.

I really don't know how best to approach it; how can I use a t/p score and turn it into something meaningful?

Is it best to return a score out of 100 with 1 being resistant and 100 being not resistant or is it best to try and predict the population mean?

(The below is the data I have for one antibiotic, so I have multiple unrelated branches of data)

My data set is {1,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,1}

Edit:

My data categories are Resistant, Intermediate, Sensitive (which have been converted into a 1,2,3 with Sensitive = 1, Resistant = 3)

Behind the data set are lab results, so antibiotic X has been tested against Disease Y, N times (with n being the number of items in my data set)

**Disease Y**

| Antibiotic X | Antibiotic Z | Antibiotic W |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am not looking for the most effective antibiotic, I need to leave that to the person administering it; my goal is to say based on the sample of data I have the population data for each antibiotic is *something*.

I think what I want to say is:

A statistical certainty/probability which category the population mean fits into (1,2,3)
e.g.
There's an 80% chance that Disease Y is resistant to Antibiotic X

Once again that's just my thought, I'm not a very experienced analyst, so if I am on the wrong track/there's a better more efficient method then please say!

Comment: I feel you need to provide more information about the problem you are trying to solve. What are the categories? What is behind your dataset? resistance of one antibiotique against different patient? What would you like to demonstrate?

Comment: I have edited to provide more information! I'm doing a data analysis apprenticeship but it's honestly farcical, I've nearly completed it and I am yet to learn anything about statistics or be given any support what so ever with it.

Comment: I think I got it... actually the type of tests you can perform depends on the how you tackle the problem. If you want to compare more than 2 groups (probably with proportion in your case), it might be challenging in the first place. If your goal is to learn, I would encourage you to start with one or two groups. The tests are simpler and certainly easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think I compare about comparisons, I just want to fit the data into it's most likely category , e.g. I don't care if X is more effective Y, I want to say X is 100% resistant, Y is 40% resistant. So I want to focus on individual Antibiotics rather than a comparison; does that make sense? So I have 22 different antibiotics I just want a score for each individual one e.g. with the data set I provided the mean is 1.44, how can I say with some certainty/probability that the population would fit into either category 1,2,3?

Comment: ok... sorry for being slow ;-) The mean of your categorical value will not give much information, or is difficult to interpret. However, using proportion can certainly help you. For instance, looking at your sample, the antibiotic is resistant in 22.22% of the tests against a given disease. Then, from this sample, you can make inference of the "population". Is this what you are looking for...?

Comment: Exactly that! No it's my fault for not explaining it very well and for also not 100% knowing what I want! I've dabbled with various inferential statistics but 99% of the time I end up with 'not statistically significant'. I've watched so many tutorials on it but without seeing an example on your data set and knowing how to interpret the results it's rather difficult. So would you create a null hypothesis along the lines of 'H0 = 0.22', or how would you approach it? (If you reply as an answer then I can mark it as solved!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, I guess it might be useful to consider determining confidence interval. From a general perspective, the resistance of each antibiotic for a specific disease should be "transformed" into proportion. For example, in the sample you provided, this antibiotic is resistant in 22.22% of cases.

So, from this sample, you can make inference on the broader population and define a confidence Interval (CI) where you can expect it includes the population proportion. Here is an example of computing this CI: https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/PH717-QuantCore/PH717_ConfidenceIntervals-OneSample/PH717_ConfidenceIntervals-OneSample5.html

It is important to keep in mind that such a test must meet some requirements to be reliable. For instance, it is common to consider that we should have at least 15 successes and 15 failures to compute such CI... which is not the case with the sample you have provided.

In R, you can look at the fonction prop.test() which might be helpful to play with it and understand better the data.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help on this!